# Name for words that have 3 or more syllables?

Tags: single-word-requests, syllables

A word with one syllable is "monosyllabic". Two syllables is "disyllabic", three is "trisyllabic", and so on. "Polysyllabic" refers to any word with more than one syllable. Is there any single term for words that have more than two (including three, four, five, and so on)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you know the adjective for two and three syllable words, where's the problem? Words that have more than two syllables are called disyllabic, trisyllabic, quadrisyllabic or, exceptionally, pentasyllabic.

Comment: Offhand, I can't think of any situation where we would have a word for "more than *two* of X", whether syllables or years or wheels or ....

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry about the confusion - I'm looking for a word that covers everything past two. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: I'd go for polysyllabic, a five-syllable word is still "polysyllabic" despite having more than three syllables

Comment: [*Having more than one syllable; **having multiple or many syllables**.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polysyllabic)

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

multisyllabic

: having more than one and usually more than three syllables :

POLYSYLLABIC

// a multisyllabic 
word

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show an example case it's hard to tell if this is appropriate, but if your requirement is for a minimum of three, then  "***3+ syllables***" might fit the bill.